# Why am I losing money after a match?

Tags: blood-bowl-legendary-edition

My winnings equals 40000 GP
But I am deducted -60000 GP (Team value [2500,2640])

So I end up actually losing 20000 GP for a match.  Why is that line being deducted and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/944026-blood-bowl/answers?qid=180878) its an intentional mechanic where if your team levels up too much (i.e. has too many high value players), you start losing a set amount of money (mine seems to be capped at 60k) after a match to prevent easy money by playing low ranked matches.

Comment: Check if you actually loose any money from your treasury. According to the Living Rulebook, this should not happen, even tough the match earnings might turn out negative (if I recall correctly). You still won't be earning any money from the games, tough.

Comment: @DJPirtu I did, I started the match with 170k, ended up with 150k